# How to handle DST with timezones in drawing scaleTime in d3 using moment

Tags: reactjs, date, d3.js, timezone, momentjs

I'm trygin to draw scaleTime on d3js using moment with DST handling in all timezones.
For now I'm drawing everything in the right way by as can you see in the screen i dont have last hour in the axis. This should be [0 ... 22, 23, 0] but if the DST exist in this day hours range then I get the only [0.... 22, 23] 
How to draw hours xScale in all timezones and in all existing DST changes.

Here's my code:

```
interface TestTimeZoneComponentState {
  timezone: string;
  width: number;
  dayBeginning: Date;
  dayEnding: Date;
}
export class TestTimeZoneComponent extends React.Component<{}, TestTimeZoneComponentState> {
  private metadata = this.getChartMetadata();
  private chartCanvas: d3.Selection<SVGSVGElement, unknown, HTMLElement, any> | undefined;
  private xScale: d3.ScaleTime<number, number> | undefined;

  private dateFromUTCTime = new Date(1572580800000);
  constructor() {
    super({});
    this.state = {
      timezone: 'America/New_York',
      width: 2000,
      dayBeginning: new Date('2019-11-03T00:00:00.000-04:00'), 
      dayEnding: new Date('2019-11-04T00:00:00.000-04:00'),
    };
  }

  public componentDidMount(): void {
    this.initializeChart();
    this.drawAxis();
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    const width = `${((this.state.width) - 10)}px`;
    const height = `${(this.state.width / 10) - 10}px`;

    const chartPlaceholderStyles = {
      width,
      height,
    };
    return (
      <>
        <h3 className='mt-4'>Test TimeZone for date: {moment.tz(this.state.dayBeginning, this.state.timezone).format()}</h3>
        <h6 className='mt-4'>Setted Timezone: <strong>{this.state.timezone}</strong></h6>
        <h6>{this.state.dayBeginning.toISOString()}</h6>
        <h6>{this.state.dayEnding.toISOString()}</h6>
        <h6 className='mt-4'>Change TimeZone:{'   '}
          <input type='text' value={this.state.timezone} onChange={(event) => this.setState({ timezone: event.target.value })}></input>
          <Button color='info' size='sm' outline onClick={() => this.redraw()}>Redraw</Button>
        </h6>
        <hr />

        <Row>
          <Col>
            <div className='activitiesChartWrapper' style={{ width: this.state.width + 'px', height: (this.state.width / 10) + 15 + 'px' }}>
              <div id='activitiesChartPlaceHolder' className='activitiesChartPlaceHolder' style={chartPlaceholderStyles}></div>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </>
    );
  }

  private getChartMetadata(): ActivitiesChartMetadata {
    const aspectRatio = { horizontal: 1500, vertical: 130 };
    const minRange = 0;
    const maxRange = 1490;
    const xAxisYPosition = aspectRatio.vertical - 20;
    const xAxisTick = maxRange / 24;
    const timeRectWidth = 50;
    const timeRectHeight = 20;
    return { aspectRatio, minRange, maxRange, xAxisYPosition, xAxisTick, timeRectWidth, timeRectHeight };
  }
  private initializeChart(): void {
    const metadata = this.getChartMetadata();
    const svg = d3.select('#activitiesChartPlaceHolder')
      .classed('svg-container', true)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
      .attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${metadata.aspectRatio.horizontal} ${metadata.aspectRatio.vertical}`)
      .classed('svg-content-responsive', true);
    this.chartCanvas = svg;
  }

  private drawAxis(): void {
    this.chartCanvas?.selectAll('.xScale').remove();
    if (!this.chartCanvas) {
      console.log('Chart canvas wasn\'t properly initialized');
      return;
    }

    const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([this.state.dayBeginning, this.state.dayEnding])
      .range([this.metadata.minRange, (this.metadata.aspectRatio.horizontal - 10)]);

    this.xScale = xScale;

    const a = this.chartCanvas
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'xScale')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(5,' + this.metadata.xAxisYPosition + ')')
      .transition().duration(100)
      .call(
        d3.axisBottom(xScale)
          .ticks(d3.timeHour.every(1))
          // @ts-ignore
          .tickFormat((d: Date) => {
            if (this.state.timezone === 'local') {
              return moment(d as Date).format('H');
            } else {
              return moment(d as Date).tz(this.state.timezone).format('H');
            }
          })
          .tickSize(5)
          .tickPadding(5),
      );
  }

  private redraw(): void {
    this.drawAxis();

  }
};
```

And there is results for now for New York Timezone DST Date change:
[image]

This issue exists only when we get two times this same hours, but if we have change time drom winter to summer then we starting with axis in point with 23 hour and ending in 23 so this is to bad.

Comment: It's certainly a problem, but I'm not sure what "the right way" is.  It might be worth asking specifically about how to present a time scale with DST transitions on [ux.stackexchange.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Also, the offset in your day end is wrong.  The day ended at `2019-11-04T00:00:00.000-05:00`.  That might be why you have a missing hour at the end.

Comment: I can't manipulate hours offset in this place. Timezone manipulating this

Comment: I need just one full day in axis 0 1,2.... 23, 0